# Open a Configuration Profile through app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, configuration-files

I have a .mobileconfig file in one URL. I am sending the Http post from xcode(When a button is clicked), the http post contains the .mobileconfig url. Can i download that file when the button is clicked ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to serving up this file. It needs to be served up with a MIME `Content-Type` of `application/x-apple-aspen-config`. You may be able to do this by adding a line to your server's configuration or `.htaccess` file in the folder with:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-apple-aspen-config .mobileconfig
</IfModule>
```

If serving the file from within PHP, you may do something like:

```
header('Content-type: application/x-apple-aspen-config; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="company.mobileconfig"');
echo $mobileconfig;
```

Comment: No no. From iPhone have you accessed/downloaded the .mobileconfig file from the browser ? When you access the link, it will open in a seperate window to install it. Likewise, i have given the link in the app, but it is not opening like browser nor it is not opening anything. My question is how to open through the application?

Comment: charset is misspelled as chatset - I tried to edit but SO keeps complaining about the edit size being less than 6 chars long.

Comment: Thank you!  Adding 'application/x-apple-aspen-config' as mime type did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Small correction: that is not "chatset", it is `Charset`. Be sure which charset you want:

```
header('Content-type: application/x-apple-aspen-config; Charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="company.mobileconfig"');
echo $mobileconfig;
```